# Using linkedin API, which is the better way of know when was accepted my invitation

Tags: social-networking, linkedin-api

Which is the best way of know when was accepted an linkedin invitation using API?

I'm developing a social search web site using linkedin among other social networks.
In my site, any user, can add many linkedin user account to your site account, for then find people from linkedin using Linkedin People Search API (http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1191.html)

with the peoples found, i could be to send and invitation or a direct message, depend of the level connection of linkedin account using for that...

Then, using Linkedin API, what is the best way to monitoring when the invitation was accepted?...

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1012), there is no way to directly monitor messages or invitations that you send via the API to another user. So you'll need to come up with some way to monitor this off-line if it is something that you really need.  One idea would be to keep track of the ID of the member's you are sending invitations to, and on subsequent (or periodic) calls to the [Connections API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1004), you could scan the returned list to see if any of the stored ID's are now connections, and take the appropriate action.

Hope this helps!